finish() not returning the intent to the previous activity which used startActivityForResult()
I have A, B, C,D as the activity in the current stack.
current stack -> |A|
I have launched B from A using startActivityForResult()
current stack -> |B|
                 |A|  

Now inside of B I have a button which opens C . I do this by startActivity()
 current stack ->. |C|
                   |B|
                   |A|

Now from C, I am launching D as a Fragment. startActivity()
 current stack. -> |D|
                   |C|
                   |B|
                   |A| 

Now from D I am launching B with the flag Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
set in the intent.
 current stack. -> |B|
                   |A|

This works fine. However when I am closing B. I am not able to pass the intent back from B to A.
I am using setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent) and then finish() to close activity B.
Inside of Activity A I am able to verify activityForResult() is called for the requestCode, however result is CANCELLED . even though I set it up using setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent) and intent is also null.
Is this expected . I think the reason is Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP cleared the activity and started a new one. However I am wondering how does that matter to A ? ideally it should only care about B finishing and passing the intent correctly
Is there a way to pass back intent and correct result back to A from B
I tried changing the intent flag to see if it fixes the problem.

Have you considered whether using multiple activities this way is a good idea? Modern Android app development tends to have few activities, sometimes just one. We use fragments or composables to represent individual screens. "Now from D I am launching B with the flag Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP set in the intent" -- I am not surprised that this messes up a previous startActivityForResult() call.

that's true, however I am constrained with this setup for now

Just close D and C and you come back to B. Do not relaunch B.
